# Prism for Xamarin forms Initialize called after BindingContext is set

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am hoping to expand on the post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359084/6558112

I do not completely understand the sequence of events that happens during view and viewmodel initialization when using Prism. Dan explained this well, but I am still missing something.

My scenario is simple, I am passing an ID in the navigation parameters that the viewmodel will use to lookup some data from a service, which is all done in the Initialize method. However, the problem is that the view properties are fired before the Initialize method is called, which means I have no data yet to display, which creates some extra work for me.

**Dan provided a great explanation of the sequence of events**

1. The View is Created (Anything in the View's ctor is executed)
2. If you have specifically attached the ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel property this will resolve the ViewModel as part of the ctor
3. If you have not specifically opted out of the ViewModelLocator's Autowire, the Navigation Service will set it for you (after the ctor has completed)
4. The NavigationService will then call IAutoInitialize/IInitialize/InitializeAsync (for Prism 7.2+... INavigatingAware.OnNavigatingTo in older versions of Prism)
5. The NavigationService will then push the Page onto the Navigation Stack (note that this may or may not be visible to the user as additional pages may have to be added first when deep linking)
6. The NavigationService will then call OnNavigatedFrom / OnNavigatedTo (this is where people often report seeing a visible delay due to binding updates.

**This is where I need some help**:

I am assuming that step 3 where Dan says "the Navigation Service will set it for you" means that the view's BindingContext is set at this time? 
So, the BindingContext is set after the ctor but before the Initialize method? 
This means that all properties set in the Initialize method will always fire twice, once when the binding is set, and again with the properties are set via Initialize or Autoinitialize?

In my case, this is not ideal, since all properties must then be raised in the Initialize method and I have to handle all the null cases.

I really don't want to do it all manually by opting out of the autowire, but I don't see any other options, am I missing something?
Anyone know if it is possible to modify Prism to delay the setting of the BindingContext until after the Initialize method has been called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The Initialize method's offered by Prism:

- IInitialize.Initialize
- IIniaializeAsync.InitializeAsync
- IAutoInitialize

Will only ever be fired ONE time.

Because the ViewModelLocator is specifically opt-out instead of opt-in there are two ways that it will work.

1. You have explicitly set the AutowireViewModel property either in your XAML or you're View's code for those who really love coded UI. This means that the BindingContext of your View will be set as part of it's constructor.
2. You have let Prism's NavigationService set the AutowireViewModel for you. This means that the View's constructor has already completed. Upon setting the property the Binding context will be set.

While I generally use the 2nd method to keep my code cleaner, only explicitly opting-in when there is an edge case that requires it, it ultimately doesn't matter which of the two methods you choose. At this point the constructors of both your View and ViewModel's have executed, and the ViewModel is set as the BindingContext of the View however Prism has not called the Initialize method's.

It is only with both the View and ViewModel fully inflated (the constructors having been called and the BindingContext set), that will Prism actually start the initialization process as explained in SO question you referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359084/6558112

Hopefully to make it a bit clearer consider the following comments in the ViewModel below

```cs
public class SampleViewModel : IInitialize, INavigationAware
{
    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        // Called when we inflate the SampleViewModel object
        // This is then added as the BindingContext of the View

        // NOTE: You CAN NOT access Navigation Parameters from here!!!!
    }

    public void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        // Called before the View (Xamarin.Forms Page) is pushed onto the Navigation Stack
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        // Called when the View is Navigated away from
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        // Called any time the View is is Navigated to, or back to... 
        // and AFTER Initialize...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for answering this so quickly, you are a machine. I think I got it straight now. Keep up the great work!