# Xamarin Forms Prism - how to access BindingContext from code behind?

Tags: forms, xamarin, prism

I need to dynamically create TableView in code behind (can't use XAML, complex scenario). I'm using Prism and using Initialize method in view model to pass some parameters and get data from the server. Problem is that Initialize is called just before pushing the view (as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626069)) and I can't find a event when I can access view model in code behind when it was fully populated.

Tried in OnAppearing and OnBindingContextChanged, but Initialize is not called yet before those events are fired.

Is this not possible with Prism?

Comment: Create it in `OnBindingContextChanged` then add it to the view hierarchy in the `Initialized` event?

Answer (score 0):

OK, not sure what happened before, but now if I get view model in code behind ctor and access it in OnAppearing it works fine.